# Drupal 7 failure to create an entity of a fieldable type I created because of null id

Tags: drupal-7

I am writing my first module and have created a fieldable entity. The only property of the entity in its schema is an 'id' which is type serial, unsigned and not null. However when I use entity_create (with no property values set) followed by $entity->save() the code fails with the following SQL error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {field_data_field_available} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_available_value) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => appointments_status [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => appointments_status [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => No ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 514 of C:\wamp\www\Drupal\modules\field\modules\field_sql_storage\field_sql_storage.module).
```

This implies to me that Drupal is trying to create entries in the 'field_data' table before it has created the entry in the entity table. I set no property values because I only have the 'id' property and surely that should be auto generated. If this was done first then it would have the id for creating the entry in the field_data table. The exact code I used is:

```
   $entity_record = entity_create($entity_name,array());
   $entity_record->save();
```

I hope someone has clues. The only work around I can see is to count the existing records, add one and use that as the new id but I can see loads of issues with this approach (clashing ids, performance etc).

Work around code:

```
  $entities = entity_load('my entity type');
  $entity_id = count($entities) + 1;
  // Create the new entity object with this ID
  $entity = entity_create('my entity type, array('id' => $entity_id));
  // Save the new entity ready to reload after this if block of code
  $entity->save();
```

My hook_entity_info is:
`function appointments_entity_info() {
  return array(
    'appointments_status' => array(
      'label' => t('Appointment status'),
      'default label' => t('Appointment status'),
      'plural label' => t('Appointment statii'),
      'entity class' => 'Entity',
      'controller class' => 'EntityAPIController',
      'views controller class' => 'EntityDefaultViewsController',
      'base table' => 'appointments_status',
      'entity keys' => array(
        'id' => 'id'
      ),
      'fieldable' => TRUE,
      // Create one default bundle of the same name
      'bundles' => array(
        'appointments_status' => array(
            'label' => t('Appointment statii'),
            ),
        ),
      // Use the default label() and uri() functions
      'label callback' => 'entity_class_label',
      'uri callback' => 'entity_class_uri',
      'module' => 'appointments',
    ),
  );
}`
Thanks
Rory

Comment: Show us your hook_entity_info() impementation first.

Comment: Thanks Artreaktor. My hook_entity_info is:

Comment: @Artreaktor - I did not understand how to use this site with my previous comment. I have now added the requested information to the original post. I hope that is OK! Rory

Comment: It's ok to edit post and add some relevant info. You can add smth like "UPD:" before new text to prevent newcomers confusion.

Comment: Your implementation looks ok. I doubt that you can pass an empty $values into [entity_create()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_create/7). It seems you have to specify entity's bundle key explicitly.

Comment: Hi @Artreaktor - can you be more specific about specifying the entity's bundle key or point me to a document about this? I have read the api doc on hook_entity_info and it seems to suggest that these are not needed if you have only one bundle of the same name but also seem to suggest not needing the 'bundles' part of hook_entity_info either! Thanks Rory

Comment: Rory, look at the link in my previous message. > $values: An array of values to set, keyed by property name. If the entity type has bundles the bundle key has to be specified.

Comment: @Rory off-topic: the plural of "status" is not "statii", but also "status". It's latin U declination. If yo use the English term, take "statuses": https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/statuses#English

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much to @Arkreaktor for pointing me in the right direction. I added a 'bundle' property to my schema - type varchar length 255. I made no changes to hook_entity_info to refer to this property but then changed my entity create code to:

```
$entity = entity_create($entity_type, 'bundle' = $entity_type);
$entity->save();
$entity_id = $entity->id;
// Re-load the new entity or loading the existing entity
$entity = entity_load_single($entity_type, $entity_id);
// Rebuild the entity object from the values on the form
entity_form_submit_build_entity($entity_type, $entity, $form, $form_state);
// Save updated entity
$entity->save();
```

And it worked!!!

I hope this helps others.
Rory